# Don't understand why this "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" exception occurs

Tags: python, bitstring

This code accepts a bitstring and converts it to a character string. The bitstring comes from a txt file that's read into the client, converted to bitstring then sent to the server.

```
def getChar(charstr):
    char = []
    for byte in charstr.split(): 
        char.append(chr(int(''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]), 2)))
    return ''.join(char)
```

The bitstring in question is:

`10010011101101111000011001011100001110001111010001101101110010111011101110100100000110010110000110010110000100001`

which calls out this line

```
char.append(chr(int(''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]), 2)))
```

and gives the error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.
```

How would I fix this?

Full Server Code:

```
import socket
import random
import sys

def getCaesar(message, key):
    enc = ""
    for char in message: 
        if char == ' ':
            enc = enc + char
        elif  char.isupper():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char)+key-65)%26+65)
        elif char.islower():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char) + key - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            enc = enc +chr((ord(char) + key - 33) % 32 + 33)

    return enc

def getBinary(bitstr):
    bit=' '.join(format(ord(char), 'b') for char in bitstr)
    return bit

def getChar(charstr):
    char = []
    for byte in charstr.split(): 
        char.append(chr(int(''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]), 2)))
    return ''.join(char)

def getBitstr(k):
    result=""
    for num in range(0,k):
        result=''.join(str(random.randint(0,1))for num in range(k))
    return result

def getXor(a,b):
    a=a.replace(" ","")
    b=b.replace(" ","")
    result = int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
    return '{0:b}'.format(result)

def Decrypt(message, key):
    enc = ""
    for char in message: 
        if char == ' ':
            enc = enc + char
        elif  char.isupper():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char)-key-65)%26+65)
        elif char.islower():
            enc = enc + chr((ord(char) - key - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            enc = enc +chr((ord(char) - key - 33) % 32 + 33)

    return enc

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostname()
port=4000
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
print("Listening...")
while True:
    c,addr=s.accept()
    print("Got connection from ",addr)
    print("Receiving...")
    l = c.recv(4096).decode()

    a=str(l)
    cipherF=open("ciphertext.txt",mode='r')
    caesar=cipherF.read()
    key=Decrypt(caesar,4)
    key=''.join(key)
    b=str(key)

    content=getXor(a,b)

    dec=getChar(content)

    if not l:
        break
    print("Decrypting...")
    print(dec)

s.close()
```

Comment: When I run `>>>int('1001001110110111100001100101110000111000111101000111101110010111011101110100100000110010110000110010110000100001', 2)` in the Python shell, no error occurs and the result is `5992109095916717662206253638822945` — so I think you need to add more code to your question showing how you're using the `getChar()` function (in a way that produces the error).

Comment: @martineau, I've posted the server code. Does this mean it's a problem with my computer or the version of python I'm using?

Comment: I don't think it's a computer or Python version problem. However just posting the full server code doesn't help much. What's need it an [mcve] that reproduces the problem. So please [edit] your question again and replace all that server code with a single call to the `getChar()` function showing the argument being passed plus what correct output would be.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure because you haven't posted a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the expected/desired output in order to be able to tell if this what you want—so it's basically just a guess—but at least it doesn't raise an `OverflowError` exception...

Note: This worked in both Python 2 and 3 (or at least did the same thing).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
def getChar(charstr):
    char = []
#    for byte in charstr.split():  # Not needed.
    for byte in charstr:
        char.append(chr(int(''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]), 2)))
    return ''.join(char)


teststr = ('100100111011011110000110010111000011100011110100011011011'
           '10010111011101110100100000110010110000110010110000100001')
result = getChar(teststr)
print(repr(result))
```

Output:

`'\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'`

Answer (score 0):

The `chr` function converts an integer to the associated character. Its behavior differs between python versions, as follows:

In python 2.x, `chr(n)` will return a one-character string consisting of the ASCII character with value `n` if `0<=n<=255`. If `n` is outside of `[0, 255]` but fits in a 64-bit signed integer, `chr(n)` raises a `ValueError` complaining that the arg isn't in `range(256)`. If `n` doesn't fit in a 64-bit signed integer, `chr(n)` raises an `OverflowError` complaining that "Python int too large to convert to C long" (as observed in the question).

In python 3.x, `chr(n)` will return a one-character string consisting of the unicode character with value `n` if `0<=n<0x110000`. If `n` is outside of `[0, 0x110000)` but fits in a 32-bit signed integer, `chr(n)` raises a value error complaining that the arg isn't in `range(0x110000)`. If `n` doesn't fit in a 32-bit signed integer, `chr(n)` raises an `OverflowError` complaining that "signed integer is greater than maximum" or "signed integer is less than minimum" (depending on the sign of `n`).

The reason this is happening in the posted code is that `string.split()` splits a string at whitespace, so the `for byte in charstr.split()` loop executes exactly once, with `byte == charstr`. Similarly, `''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]` is just a long way of saying `byte` (i.e. "the string generated by concatenating each character of `byte`"). So the code in question is converting the entire 113-bit string to an integer. The first bit is a 1, so it takes at least 113 bits to store it, which means it definitely won't fit in either a 32- or 64-bit signed integer, so it falls into the `OverflowError` case on both 2.x and 3.x.